# How do I resolve ConfigurationErrorsException when running MVC3 project on a server with MVC3 & 4 installed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a project that was developed on a machine with MVC3 installed.  I copied the project to a machine that has both3 MVC and MVC4 installed. For some reason I am getting the error below. MVC3 and MVC4 are supposed to be able to run side by side. I think the error has something to do with MVC4 being installed, since the membership provider changed between 3 and 4. I am not sure how to isolate the problem. How do I resolve ConfigurationErrorsException when running an MVC3 project on a dev machine that has both MVC3 and MVC4 installed?

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (C:\Projects\Acme\BOM&MRP\AcmeWidget\Acme.Widget.Web\web.config line 42)
  Source=System.Web
  BareMessage=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Filename=C:\Projects\Acme\BOM&MRP\AcmeWidget\Acme.Widget.Web\web.config
  Line=42
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Security.Membership.Initialize()
       at System.Web.Security.Membership.get_Provider()
  InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
       Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
            at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
            at System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreatePublicInstance(Type type)
            at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)
       InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
            Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            Source=Acme.Widget.DAL
            StackTrace:
                 at Acme.Widget.DAL.Utilities.GetRegistryValue(String registryKeyPath, String valueName) in C:\Projects\Acme\BOM&MRP\AcmeWidget\Acme.Widget.DAL\Utilities.cs:line 67
                 at Acme.Widget.DAL.Utilities.GetConnectionString() in C:\Projects\Acme\BOM&MRP\AcmeWidget\Acme.Widget.DAL\Utilities.cs:line 15
                 at Acme.Widget.DAL.StoredProcedureRepository..ctor() in C:\Projects\Acme\BOM&MRP\AcmeWidget\Acme.Widget.DAL\StoredProcedureRepository.cs:line 21
                 at Acme.Widget.Provider.Membership..ctor() in C:\Projects\Acme\BOM&MRP\AcmeWidget\Acme.Widget.Provider\Membership.cs:line 18
            InnerException:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide code at line number 18 in membership.cs file.   Acme.Widget.Provider\Membership.cs:line 18

Comment: _repository = new StoredProcedureRepository(); is the code at line number 18 in membership.cs. There was a bug with the way a connection string was being built. Thank you for helping me pinpoint this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was caused by the way the connection string was being built. The configuration error was not helpful in diagnosing the problem, but Ankush Jain's comment above lead to looking in the correct place. The connection string is stored in the registry. The new machine is 64 bit and the old one is 32. After updating the code to check the environment, the code works fine.